# Derivative existence theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

Has anyone here heard of the **Derivative existence theorem**?

> **Derivative existence theorem:** For $f$ defined on some interval
>   including $a$, $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there
>   exists a function $\varphi $, which is continuous at $a$, and
>   satisfies $\forall x\leq $ interval, $f(x) - f(a) = \varphi(x)(x-a)$.
>
> In this case, $f'(a)=\varphi(a)$.

I heard that the Chain Rule Theorem for derivatives is much easier to prove using the existence theorem.

Comment: It's not so much a theorem as an alternative phrasing of the definition [unless it is the one used first, then the other is the alternative]. I wouldn't say _much_, but that formulation has advantages for proofs.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @Phira The question is exactly what you see on the first line of the post.

Comment: @AJR I do not believe that you are looking for the answers "Yes/No". So, again: what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't heard of the Derivative Existence Theorem, but the statement looks familiar. Below is the proof as well as the proof of the Chain Rule using it.

**Proof of the Derivative Existence Theorem:** Let $f$ be a function defined on $(a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ which is differentiable at $a$. Define

$$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} & \text{if}\ x \neq a\\
&\\
\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} & x = a.
\end{cases}$$

Then $\varphi(x)$ is continuous at $a$, $f(x) - f(a) = \varphi(x)(x - a)$, and $\varphi(a) = f'(a)$.

Conversely, if $f(x) - f(a) = \varphi(x)(x - a)$ for some $\varphi$ which is continuous at $a$, then for $x \neq a$

$$\varphi(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}.$$

As $\varphi$ is continuous at $a$,

$$\varphi(a) = \lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}.$$

So $f'(a)$ exists and is equal to $\varphi(a)$.

$\hspace{16.8cm}\square$

---

**Chain Rule:** Let $g$ be a function which is differentiable at $a$ and let $f$ be a differentiable at $g(a)$. Then $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $(f\circ g)'(a) = f'(g(a))g'(a)$.

**Proof of the Chain Rule:** We have $g(x) - g(a) = \varphi_g(x)(x - a)$, and $f(x) - f(g(a)) = \varphi_f(x)(x - g(a))$ where $\varphi_g$ is continuous at $a$ with $g'(a) = \varphi(a)$, and $\varphi_f$ is continuous at $g(a)$ with $f'(g(a)) = \varphi_f(g(a))$. Then

$$(f\circ g)(x) - (f\circ g)(a) = f(g(x)) - f(g(a)) = \varphi_f(g(x))(g(x) - g(a)) = \varphi_f(g(x))\varphi_g(x)(x-a).$$

As $g$ is differentiable at $a$, $g$ is continuous at $a$ so $\varphi_f(g(x))$ is continuous at $a$, and therefore $\varphi_f(g(x))\varphi_g(x)$ is continuous at $a$. By the Derivative Existence Theorem, $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $(f\circ g)'(a) = \varphi_f(g(a))\varphi_g(a) = f'(g(a))g'(a)$.

$\hspace{16.8cm} \square$